# What types are types of in c?

Tags: c++, c, types

I'm wondering what type types have in c. For example, how would I do something like this.

```
type type_a = int;
type type_b = float;
```

In context of my project, I'm trying to make a function that can be used as follows.

```
// createSelector(const char *name, ...)

Selector *mySelector = createSelector("myMethod", int, char);

// Selector->types contains all the passed types in an array.
// Selector->name contains the name of the method.
```

If c does not support this functionality, I can easily transfer my project to c++. However, I would then need to know what the type is in c++. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Why does `Selector-types` have to have all the types passed?

Comment: I'm building a runtime for a language I've designed, which will operate similarly to the Objective-C runtime. However, my goal is to keep the usage of the runtime to a minimum, to increase execution speed. My primary reason for needing the runtime, is to have it so that methods can be added to classes after definition.

Comment: @Matthew: Then I'd recommend going with one of the many popular and mature runtime projects that already exist, such as the JVM or the CLR. I don't really see what you mean about adding methods to classes after definition -- if that's the case, just define a new class that inherits publicly from the old one, and add new methods in your new inherited class. Or implement something like C#'s "Extension methods", which allow this kind of extension without actually modifying the original class.

Comment: The goal is that the runtime is only included when needed. The language is meant to run at the same speed as C++, but when dynamic features are used the runtime is automatically included. The reason I'm hesitant to write my own type system, or use a virtual machine, is that speed is a major consideration. Furthermore, this language will be used on microcontrollers. So I would rather not have to include both the compiled program, and a virtual machine to run it.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: If you don't understand the meaning of "adding methods to classes after definition," I suggest you take a look at JavaScript and other dynamic languages that allow you to add properties or methods to a class at runtime.

Comment: @Jim: I'm not saying I don't understand the concept. I'm saying I don't understand why you'd want the concept. In Javascript the class concept is very different from that exposed in C++/C#/Java. (The Java class is essentially a hash table containing function pointers, while the other languages share a "Big blob of data + completely unrelated methods that act on it" model) The second part of my answer is how one would implement adding to a class that's already defined on top of a system designed to not allow this, like the JVM or CLR -- just extend from the existing class to add what youwant.

Comment: @Matthew: Both the JVM and CLR already have JIT-ing -- I very very highly doubt you're going to be able to beat them, considering they already almost beat C and C++ in many cases. They already perform optimizations like you describe on the fly by compiling your application down to native code at runtime.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't do that in either C or C++. The ability to perform such type-based introspection is called "Reflection", and it's simply not a feature in C or C++.

Honestly though, if you find yourself needing something like this you need to take an extremely long, hard look at your design -- needing things like this, even in those languages that support them is usually indicative of papering over a poor design.

Comment: I'm attempting to build a runtime for a language I've designed. I can't see any ways to avoid this, besides making all the types go through the runtime. However, thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @Matthew Lynn: Yes, you would need to write your own type system. You can't piggyback on top of the C or C++ native types and expect a facility like this to be provided for you. Real machines don't know the concept of a "class", and therefore compilers aren't required to encode information about the classes themselves into the resultant binary (beyond that exposed by `std::type_info`).

Comment: I agree that misuses are not rare, and there's always a way without it. However, using introspection doesn't necessarily mean a bad design. If your language supports it, and your code will be heavily simplified, then use it. But be aware that code simplification should NOT be the only consideration. Unfortunately, the closer thing C++ has is RTTI, which is far from being a **complete** introspection mechanism.

Comment: @Matthew, use enums to create your own type system - e.g. `enum { Int, Real, String, ... };`

Comment: @jweyrich: Yes, there are legitimate uses of reflection (i.e. JUnit/NUnit), but the vast majority of the time I see people using it, they're using it to make APIs that are "stringly-typed", which is a horrible thing to do in the first place. Needing something like that at all is an indication that the types you have simply aren't well designed. This makes it difficult for code to choose the right type to instantiate, which results in these kind of dependencies on reflection.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: It's a real disappointment. I've seen this "string-tipification" in the past, and I think these "programmers" should've been prosecuted for criminal act.

Comment: @jweyrich: The tendency to stringly-type things might be less severe if there were easier ways of imputing value semantics to immutable classes.  It's often easier to provide a way of converting a type to and from a string (serializing it, basically) than it is to provide a "native" hashing, equality, and magnitude comparison operators.

Comment: @supercat: When I say "stringly" typed I mean choosing the instantiated type based on a string, not conversion of an object to/from a string. Serialization (and the more general memento pattern) can be extremely useful and is required for things like network transmission. And it doesn't require reflection to operate.

Comment: @Billy: I wasn't thinking of serialization for transport, but rather serialization for storing in a collection.  Actually, using strings as type selectors can be reasonable as part of serialization, if one uses a dictionary of factories to generate objects.

Comment: @supercat: strings are quite expensive in contrast with numbers. For example, I wouldn't use "uint"+value. It may be a benefit only for larger and complex types, but IMO it's generally not clever.

Answer (score 5):

Both C and C++ do not allow you to directly work with types. To do the type of thing you're suggesting, you'll need to look into [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/), although you probably won't be able to do exactly the type of thing you want but you might be able to get rather close.

```
// template <typename T, typename T2>
// Selector* createSelector(const char* name)
Selector *mySelector = createSelector<int,char>("myMethod");
```

Comment: Don't see how you could meet the requirement `Selector->types contains all the passed types in an array.` using templates...

Comment: @Billy:  Don't see why you'd want to meet that requirement, either.

Comment: @Billy In addition, that requirement could theoretically be met in C++0x: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Variadic_templates

Comment: @user: No, it could not. There's nothing at runtime exposed by templates like this. Varadic templates are extremely different from an array of types. One operates entirely at compile time, while the other completely at runtime.

Comment: @Billy While you wouldn't necessarily have an exact array of types as a member of the Selector instance, you would still have the ability to have a collection of the types in a specific instantiation of the Selector class. You might not be able to do every last thing you would want to do with an array, but it would get you close and depending on the needs of the OP possibly even meet his specific needs. In addition, chapter 3 of MC++D covers typelists, which may also do what OP wants without requiring C++0x features.

Comment: @user: You wouldn't even be able to iterate over the types. I think that fails the most basic use of such a facility.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Billy ONeal's answer I should note that compile-time type selection is possible in C++, by means of [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming)

Comment: +1 -- but you don't need to be doing TMP in order to make generic things happen using templates.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have mentioned, you can't refer directly to a type without reflection, which isn't a feature in C or C++. C++ at least has templates, which works for many generic algorithms.

But to answer your question for C, there is at least one library that attempts to provide this for its own needs. The [Message-Passing Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) must send and receive data across many different platforms, where datatypes can be different sizes. So MPI uses constants to indicate the datatype as a function parameter. For example:

```
char buffer [BUFFERSIZE];
MPI_Send (buffer, BUFFERSIZE, MPI_CHAR, ...);  // MPI_CHAR indicates a char array
```

(It's worth noting that [Boost's MPI bindings](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/mpi.html) don't need the type constants and would just effectively call `send(buffer)`.)

Hopefully you won't need to go down this road.

Comment: +1 -- this essentially amounts to "write your own type system"